# python database migration on application startup

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flyway, alembic

I am currently developing a new app against postgresql.
For ORM and migrations I thought to use SQLAlchemy with alembic.

As I would like to handle migrations on application startup I wondered if there are any python projects (like FlyWay + Spring for java) which already handle this problem.

If this can be handled using other solutions than SQLAlchemy and Alembic I would also consider this helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy and Alembic is cool for Python.

But what about yoyo ? https://pypi.org/project/yoyo-migrations/

Answer (score 2):

Pyway https://pypi.org/project/pyway is a database versioning and migration tool inspired by Flyway!